# Query status of inner array of in MongoDB using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User schema with followers array like below,

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  followers: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  following: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
});
```

When i query for list of Users i need two extra fields isFollowing and isFollower
(isFollowing exists in my following array, isFollower exists in followers array)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) the `followers` and `following` arrays:

```
const users = await User.findOne({ ... })
                         .populate('followers')
                         .populate('following');
```